# Why does my list function do not work in this question if i directly add answer but works if i create a copy of list

Tags: java, list, algorithm, recursion, arraylist

This is a basic recursion question where we have to return the number of combination possible by using any element infinite times.
The question is

### Given a set of candidate numbers (candidates) (without duplicates) and a target number (target), find all unique combinations in candidates where the candidate numbers sums to target

```
public List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
 public  void combinations(
            int[]arr, int i, int target, List<Integer> ans) {
       if( target==0)
       {
           List<Integer> l= new ArrayList<>(ans);
    list.add(l);
    //if i do list.add(ans) it does not work
       return ;
       }

       if( target<0||i==arr.length){
           return ;
       }


       for( int j=i;j<arr.length;j++)
       {
            ans.add(arr[j]);
        combinations(arr,j,target-arr[j],ans);

           ans.remove(ans.size()-1);
       }

    }
```

The main code is :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[]a= {2,3,5};
     int target = 8;
        Solution s= new Solution();
        s.combinations(a,0,target,new ArrayList<>());
        System.out.println(s.list);
    }
```

Now if make a new copy of the  list variable(ans) in a variable (l) then my code works fine but if i directly add (ans) variable to the list then it does not work and an empty arraylist is returned . I am not able to understand why?

Comment: hello, could you state, what is the aim of your method? You are talking about a sum, but retrieve a list of number lists.

Comment: Please  state your objective with this and show the parameters you are passing to the method.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum This is the link to the question.

Comment: The leetcode function name was this so i posted it as such . Sorry if it caused confusion

Answer (score 0):

There are updates to `ans`:

```
for ( int j = i; j < arr.length; j++ ) {
    ans.add( arr[j] );
    combinations( arr, j, target - arr[j], ans );
    ans.remove( ans.size() - 1 );
}
```

Unless `ans` is copied, those updates will be visible through the reference which was added to `list`.  In particular, the `remove` done after the call to `combinations` will be visible.

Comment: Thanks Thomas . I just read about deep and shallow copy on internet